# Kodi 17.0 won't launch ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kodi

Today I update my kodi and after the update it won't launch. It's just open the icon and then closing it.
I am running ubuntu 16.04 and installed the kodi from the terminal. The version of the kodi is 17.0 beta

Problem solved after update.

Comment: things has been fine by know, I installed the beta and reinstall the stable version and everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the nightly and then reinstall stable version.

You can see the full guide at the kodi wiki page: https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Downgrading_to_a_stable_version_from_a_development_version

to do it you need to run this line in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt-get remove kodi*
sudo apt-get install kodi
```